# How to apply a "mixin" class to an old-style base class

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

I've written a mixin class that's designed to be layered on top of a new-style class, for example via

```
class MixedClass(MixinClass, BaseClass):
    pass
```

What's the smoothest way to apply this mixin to an old-style class?  It is using a call to `super` in its `__init__` method, so this will presumably (?) have to change, but otherwise I'd like to make as few changes as possible to `MixinClass`.  I should be able to derive a subclass that makes the necessary changes.

I'm considering using a class decorator on top of a class derived from `BaseClass`, e.g.

```
@old_style_mix(MixinOldSchoolRemix)
class MixedWithOldStyleClass(OldStyleClass)
```

where `MixinOldSchoolRemix` is derived from `MixinClass` and just re-implements methods that use `super` to instead use a class variable that contains the class it is mixed with, in this case `OldStyleClass`.  This class variable would be set by `old_style_mix` as part of the mixing process.

`old_style_mix` would just update the class dictionary of e.g. `MixedWithOldStyleClass` with the contents of the mixin class (e.g. `MixinOldSchoolRemix`) dictionary.

Is this a reasonable strategy?  Is there a better way?  It seems like this would be a common problem, given that there are numerous available modules still using old-style classes.

Comment: would I be out of line for suggesting a conversion of the old style class to a new style class?

Comment: @aaronasterling: If I could cause it to be retroactively updated in all installations of the standard library, I would definitely do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This class variable would be set by
>   old_style_mix as part of the mixing
>   process.

...I assume you mean: "...on the class it's decorating..." as opposed to "on the class that is its argument" (the latter would be a disaster).

> old_style_mix would just update the
>   class dictionary of e.g.
>   MixedWithOldStyleClass with the
>   contents of the mixin class (e.g.
>   MixinOldSchoolRemix) dictionary.

No good -- the information that `MixinOldSchoolRemix` derives from `MixinClass`, for example, is **not** in the former's dictionary.  So, `old_style_mix` must take a different strategy: for example, build a new class (which I believe has to be a new-style one, because old-style ones do *not* accept new-style ones as `__bases__`) with the appropriate sequence of bases, as well as a suitably tweaked dictionary.

> Is this a reasonable strategy?

With the above provisos.

> It seems like this would be a common
>   problem, given that there are numerous
>   available modules still using
>   old-style classes.

...but mixins with classes that were never designed to take mixins are definitely **not** a common design pattern, so the problem isn't common at all (I don't remember seeing it even once in the many years since new-style classes were born, and I was actively consulting, teaching advanced classes, and helping people with Python problems for many of those years, as well as doing a lot of software development myself -- I do tend to have encountered any "reasonably common" problem that people may have with features which have been around long enough!-).

Here's example code for what your class decorator could do (if you prefer to have it in a class decorator rather than directly inline...):

```
>>> class Mixo(object):
...   def foo(self):
...     print 'Mixo.foo'
...     self.thesuper.foo(self)
... 
>>> class Old:
...   def foo(self):
...     print 'Old.foo'
... 
>>> class Mixed(Mixo, Old):
...   thesuper = Old
... 
>>> m = Mixed()
>>> m.foo()
Mixo.foo
Old.foo
```

If you want to build `Mixed` under the assumed name/binding of `Mixo` in your decorator, you could do it with a call to `type`, or by setting `Mixed.__name__ = cls.__name__` (where `cls` is the class you're decorating).  I think the latter approach is simpler (warning, untested code -- the above interactive shell session is a real one, but I have not tested the following code):

```
def oldstylemix(mixin):
    def makemix(cls):
        class Mixed(mixin, cls):
            thesuper = cls
        Mixed.__name__ = cls.__name__
        return Mixed
    return makemix
```